# Show that there exist continuous functions $g(x)\leq f(x) \leq h(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, and $\int_{0}^{1} (h(x)-g(x))dx < \epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function and let $\epsilon >0$. Show that there exist continuous functions $g,h:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)\leq f(x) \leq h(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, and $\int_{0}^{1} (h(x)-g(x))dx < \epsilon$.

Since $f$ is a Riemann integrable. For all $\epsilon >0$, there exist a partition $P_{\epsilon}$ of $[0,1]$ such that $U(P_{\epsilon},f)-L(P_{\epsilon},f)<\epsilon$, and
$L(P_{\epsilon},f)\leq \int_{0}^{1}fdx\leq U(P_{\epsilon},f)$.

Now I want to show that there exist $g,h$ are continuous, I am confused here, how I claim my $g(x)=U(P_{\epsilon},f)$. and it is continuous.

Can anyone suggest me some hint for existence of two continuous function here.

Answer (score 2):

$L(P_\epsilon,f)$ is the integral of a step function $G\le f$ that is constant on each of the intervals of the partition $P_\epsilon$.  To get $g$, modify $G$ near each of its jumps to make it continuous.  Thus if $G(x) = d$ for $a \le x \le b$ and
$e$ for $b < x \le c$, with $d < e$, take $g(x) = d + m (x-b)$ for
$b \le x \le b + (e-d)/m$ for suitable $m$.
Similarly on the other side to get $h$.